# Stop List of Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, java-threads

I have an array list of Threads and I want to stop all threads in the list if the cancel button pressed from GUI. Is there any way to stop all these threads?

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
EncryptThread encryptThread = null;
for(int j=0;j<fileEncrytionList.size();j++){
    encryptThread = new EncryptThread();
    encryptThread.setFilePath(fileEncrytionList.get(j));
    encryptThread.setOutPutFile(fileName);
    Thread t = new Thread(encryptThread);
    t.start();
    threads.add(t); 
}

if(cancel button pressed) // stop all threads from arraylist
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thread cancellation is a cooperative task in Java - the threads need to be programmed to respond to some kind of a cancellation signal. The two most common ways to do this are:

1. *Interruption*. There is a [`Thread#interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) method which is what most JDK methods sensitive to cancellation use. E.g. most blocking methods will detect interruption. Ever seen an `InterruptedException`, e.g. from `Thread.sleep()`? That's it! The `sleep()` method is blocking, potentially long-running, and cancellable. If the thread is interrupted while sleeping, it will wake up and throw an `InterruptedException`.

   Upon receiving an interrupt signal, a task should stop what it's doing and throw an `InterruptedException` which you can catch in the upper layers, log something along the lines of *"Shutting down, bye!"*, ideally reinterrupt the thread and let it die. If you've programmed some blocking tasks into your threads, checking `Thread.interrupted()` is one way to handle cancellation.
2. A flag. If your thread is doing some repetitive work all over again in a loop, that loop can be changed to:

   ```java
   private volatile boolean shouldContinue = true;

   @Override
   public void run() {
       while (shouldContinue) {
           // ...do work.
       }
   }

   public void cancelPlease() {
       shouldContinue = false;
   }
   ```

   ...or something along those lines.

The general message is - your runnables need to know they're cancellable, and they need to cooperate. Whatever you do, do NOT call the [`Thread#stop()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) method.